# Android HttpClient, HttpPost and AsyncTask Fatal Exception #1

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am newbie on Android and I am developing an app that post some informations to a php script however I'm getting too much exceptions.

Here is my code:

```
 package com.example.testapp;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HttpTraitement extends AsyncTask<HttpClient, Integer, HttpResponse> {

    private Context context;

    public HttpTraitement (Context context) 
    {
        this.context = context;     
    }

    @Override
    protected HttpResponse doInBackground(HttpClient... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HttpResponse response = null;
        params[0] = new DefaultHttpClient();


        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://namedomain/test.php");


        try {
            response = params[0].execute(httppost); 

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this.context, "Caught ClientProtocolException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this.context, "Caught IOException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this.context, "Exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                  
        }

        return response;

    }






}
```

LogCat Stack:

```
06-12 14:54:01.455: E/Trace(1244): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-12 14:54:04.166: E/AndroidRuntime(1244): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-12 14:54:04.166: E/AndroidRuntime(1244): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-12 14:54:04.166: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
06-12 14:54:04.166: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
06-12 14:54:04.166: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
06-12 14:54:04.166: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
06-12 14:54:04.166: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
06-12 14:54:04.166: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-12 14:54:04.166: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-12 14:54:04.166: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-12 14:54:04.166: E/AndroidRuntime(1244): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
06-12 14:54:04.166: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at com.example.testapp.HttpTraitement.doInBackground(HttpTraitement.java:29)
06-12 14:54:04.166: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at com.example.testapp.HttpTraitement.doInBackground(HttpTraitement.java:1)
06-12 14:54:04.166: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at 
android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-12 14:54:04.166: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
```

===================================================================

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is how you want to call your async task:

```
HttpTraitement task = new HttpTraitement(this);
task.execute("http://namedomain/test.php");
```

In order to do that, you must change your async task the following way:

```
public class HttpTraitement extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, HttpResponse> {

    private Context context;

    public HttpTraitement (Context context) 
    {
        this.context = context;     
    }

    @Override
    protected HttpResponse doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpResponse response = null;
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);

        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            response = client.execute(httppost); 

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this.context, "Caught ClientProtocolException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this.context, "Caught IOException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this.context, "Exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                  
        }

        return response;

    }

}
```

Please note that the method `execute()` must be called only once for each async task object. Thus if you want to call it for more than one URL, you must do this:

```
HttpTraitement task1 = new HttpTraitement(this);
task1.execute("http://namedomain/test1.php");
HttpTraitement task2 = new HttpTraitement(this);
task2.execute("http://namedomain/test2.php");
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I've changed it to 

`public class HttpTraitement extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, HttpResponse>`

And it's working very well

Comment: I've changed my answer, please take a look at it now. The async task is now parameterized with whichever URL you want to access.

Comment: Yes, it's good for me ... now I have a clear idea about the HttpClient and AsyncTask. Thank you again

Answer (score 2):

When calling `execute()` on the `AsyncTask` you are not passing any parameters (so length of `params` is **0**).
 Then inside `doInBackground` you attempt to put a `DefaultHttpClient` into the `params` array at position 0 but that position does not exist.

The params argument is so you can pass parameters to the `AsyncTask` for execution. You shouldn't be altering it within the `AsyncTask` -- you should treat it as read only.

Answer (score 0):

In order to call an async task you got to create a new object of a class Httptraitement in your MainClass

```
HttpTraitement http=new HttpTraitement();
```

then you got to execute an asyncTask an path the params, in your case HttpClient params;

```
HttpClient client= new DefaultHttpClient();
htt.execute(client);
```

in your Log:

```
 06-12 14:54:04.166: E/AndroidRuntime(1244): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
06-12 14:54:04.166: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at com.example.testapp.HttpTraitement.doInBackground(HttpTraitement.java:29)
```

that means that you havn't passed a single parameter... here you go